# How to rewrite relative paths/links depth via jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Have code:

```
<link href="assets/css/example.css">
```

> **For example**
>
> Page URL: http://sitename.com/section/page.html
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> <link href="../assets/css/example.css">
> ```
>
> etc. ...

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with jQuery? If you have control of the server, it would be better to change the `href`s there.

Comment: `$('link').each(function(i,v){var x = $(v).attr('href'); $(v).attr('href', '../' + x); });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.URL` to get the Page URL and count the `/` slashes in it. Depending on the count, add a `../` in front of the `href` attribute.

```
$(function(){
    var url = document.URL,
        arr = url.split('/'),
        arrLen = arr.length,
        links = $('link');

    $.each(links, function(){
        var link = $(this),
            href = link.prop('href'),
            i = 2, // start at the 3th slash
            path = "";

        for (; i < arrLen; i++){
            path += '../';
        }

        link.prop('href', path + href);
    });
});
```